# Given the Hostname, get Host from ~/.ssh/config

Tags: awk, ssh

Is there a way to get the `Host` from the `.ssh/config` given a `Hostname`?. For example

```
Host foo
Hostname 111.11.111.111
User root
Port 22
```

If I know the host, I can get the hostname, like this:

```
~|> ssh -G foo | grep -E '\bhostname ' | cut -d " " -f 2
111.11.111.111
```

Is there any way to do it viceversa? I know the ip (111.11.111.111) but want to get `foo` ?

Comment: How about using `nslookup` here? Use something like `ssh -G your_ip | grep ....` didn't test it but try it out once and let me know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 does not work with ip ```-G      Causes ssh to print its configuration after evaluating Host and Match blocks and exit.``` as far as I see...

Comment: Actually why we are doing `ssh` here you can do like `nslookup ip_address` and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: That's not necessarily equivalent, the `Host` entry is just an identifier for the record when doing `ssh foo`, it doesn't need to match the DNS name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, adding one more of getting hostname from ~/.ssh/config file.

***1st Solution:*** Prepared and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v ip="111.11.111.111" -v RS="" '$3=="Hostname" && $4==ip && $1=="Host"{print $2}'  ~/.ssh/config
```

***OR***

```
awk -v ip="111.11.111.111" -v RS="" '
$3=="Hostname" && \
$4==ip && \
$1=="Host"{
  print $2
}'  ~/.ssh/config
```

***2nd Solution:*** Using `tac` with `awk` here.

```
tac ~/.ssh/config | awk -v ip="111.11.111.111" '$1=="Hostname" && $NF==ip{getline;if($1=="Host"){print $2;exit}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -G` seems to expect a single host, but you could try to parse config file yourself. Something like this seems to work on my system:

```
awk -v h="111.11.111.111" \
      '$1 == "Host" {r = $2} \
       $1 == "Hostname" && $2 == h {print r; exit}' \
     ~/.ssh/config
```

Of course this is quite fragile, e.g in case an entry is missing the `Hostname` field

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v ip='111.11.111.111' '{f[$1]=$2} $1=="Hostname" && $2==ip{print f["Host"]}' file
foo
```